# Search file contents for a match with regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression which matches a date format like : `26 August 2011`
and I'm trying to read each line in a file and capture the line that contains the date in above format. But it does not seem to be working:

```
Regex test = new Regex(@"^((31(?!\ (Feb(ruary)?|Apr(il)?|June?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov)(ember)?)))|((30|29)(?!\ Feb(ruary)?))|(29(?=\ Feb(ruary)?\ (((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])\ (Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Ma(r(ch)?|y)|Apr(il)?|Ju((ly?)|(ne?))|Aug(ust)?|Oct(ober)?|(Sep(?=\b|t)t?|Nov|Dec)(ember)?)\ ((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$");
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(outputFile);

while ((line2 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(line2);
    foreach (Match match in test.Matches(line2))
    {
        v += match.Value;
    }
}
```

Ok, so this is the scenario..
1st  - If line contains: "26 August 2011", it returns that date.
2nd - If line contains : " some text etc 26 August 2011", it returns null.

Any idea how this issue can be tackled?

Comment: By giving `test` a more appropriate value perhaps?

Comment: I really love how intuitive Regex is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading `^` character in your regular expression says, "match starting at the beginning of the line." And the last character is `$`, meaning that the line has to end with the expression. So if your line contains anything other than a date in the format you specified, the regular expression isn't going to match.

Remove the `^` at the front and the `$` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Jim. This worked perfectly. I guess it was my mistake as I just copy and pasted it from another site without having any idea on how itworks. On the same token I would appreciate if anyone has regular expression for: dd-MMM-yy and 26th August 2011. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing test is defined as `Regex test=new Regex("26 August 2011");`

Try this

```
StreamReader file = new StreamReader(outputFile); 

while ((line2 = file.ReadLine()) != null) 
{ 
    lines.Add(line2); 
    if (test.IsMatch(line2)) 
    { 
        v += line2;
    } 
}
```

Albeit you probably want to use a StringBuilder for performance  (eg `v = new StringBuilder()`) and then instead of `v += line2` you do `v.Append(line2)`

--UPDATE

Reading your updated answer with the provided regex, if you just use your existing code and remove the `^` at the begining of the regex and the `$` at the end then your code will find all dates within the file regardless of position if that is what you are after.

Comment: Is there any way it can return only the date and discard all the other text in the line?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? Are you trying to find all the rows that have just a date or are you trying to match the dates within a row that can have other text?

Comment: ok let me explain...
There are multiple lines in a text file, but only one line will contain a date in that format (dd MMM yyyy). All I want to do is extract that date and disregard all other text that may be within that line.
The thing is that if the line contains only that date then it retrieves successfully else if it has some other text along with the date I'm not able to retrieve. 
Hope this clarifies my problem much better.